# How to find out which thread holding mutex if the sturct of pthread_mutex_t only have one int32_t?

Tags: c++, unity-game-engine, android-ndk, pthreads, mutex

Firstly, I get Unity Android project and using NDK(R19 which download by Unity) and Cmake to programed my app.
The stuct of pthead_mutex_t looks like below. And it's not define **LP64**.

```
typedef struct {
#if defined(__LP64__)
  int32_t __private[10];
#else
  int32_t __private[1];
#endif
} pthread_mutex_t;
```

When I google "How to determine the thread holding a mutex", all answers told data.**owner** will shows that. But I cannot find that.
So what else can I do to get that?

Edit:

Does anyone know about __private[1] ? What data will saved in it?

Comment: `__owner` is an implementation detail of glibc, which android doesn't use. It wouldn't be expected to work with other libc implementations. I don't think there is any pthread interface for this.

Comment: There is no *standard* way to determine the owner of a mutex. And if you are using mutexes properly, there is never a *need* to know.

Comment: Well, sad to hear that.

Comment: This sounds like an XY problem.  What do you imagine doing with the information if you could get it?